# Vuejs modal component and external JS script

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using Laravel and Vue.js to make an app. In a blade page I have a google map plugin (lat, long picker) that needs a script library like this:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

My plugin that shows the map:

```html
<div class="gllpLatlonPicker">
  <div class="gllpMap" style="width: 100%; height: 330px">location</div>
  <input class="gllpLatitude" :value="$parent.shop_for_edit.lat" />
  <input class="gllpLongitude" :value="$parent.shop_for_edit.long" />
  <input class="gllpZoom" type="hidden" value="11" />
  <input class="gllpLatitude" id="lat" size="10" type="text" :value="$parent.shop_for_edit.lat" />
  <input
    class="gllpLongitude"
    id="long"
    size="10"
    type="text"
    :value="$parent.shop_for_edit.long"
  />
</div>
```

**My problem**: I want to create the edit page in Vue.js modal and load that map picker on it and as you know, modals are a component and we use `v-if` to make it open and until its not opened, my script will not going to work.

I can fix it by using `v-show` instead of `v-if` but by this way my `mounted()` will not working and this component is already opened.

Is there any way to recompile the DOM in Vue component to update with script and work fine??

Comment: I dont know your code but have you tried watching the property triggering the v-show and when it changes run whatever you were running on mounted (dont know what you running on mounted tho, might not work)

Comment: @rule its very simple : i have a map plugin that needs a script library url. when i use that map in my vue modal component (the components which are not loaded first time), this plugin not working and not showing at all

Comment: From what i remember, the google maps API require you to have an API_KEY, and you can pass a callback that will be called when it is ready, arent you trying to use the API without it being ready? or without a valid API_KEY? or does that "picker" explicitly says it doesnt need the API_KEY?

EDIT: nvm , with v-show it works, so it is not related to api keys

Comment: @rule plase ignore the API. as i said : my plugin is working in laravel blade as well. my problem is about vuejs modal component

Comment: just to note your second input is missing the ':' in the value

Comment: @rule . i know that